# c# Discord BOT : send string with underscore (escape underscore in Visual Studio string)

Tags: c#, string, discord

I want to send string with several underscore `"__hello__its_me_"` but Discord interpret it as markdown and underline or italic my string.

I know I have to escape the underscore with backslash but in Visual Studio I can't escape underscore (unrecognized escape sequence).

How can I build this string and send it to Discord escaping underscore ?

Comment: you need to escape the backslash in C# (ie:   "\\\\_\\\\_hello\\\\_\\\\_its\\\\_me\\\\_" ) in order to produce  "\\_\\_hello\\_\\_its\\_me\\_" to Discord

Comment: ho yes why I don't think about that before thanks ! I need to double my backslash like this `"\\_\\_hello\\_\\_"`

Comment: Could do as @MLeblanc said as (s)he is quite correct.  Personally, I would use the @"text" way of doing it.  The @ symbol at the start of a string allows you to type precisely what you want into the string.  No need to escape anything that way.  (at least on the C# side).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: @DanRayson thanks that is what i'm looking for it's better than escape escape char. `string a = @"\_\_hello\_\_";` works perfectly.

Comment: Can you use this - `var literalString = @"__hello__its_me_";`
Which is what @Ray Dawson wrote but with example code

Comment: @Coops no I need to escape underscore because Discord interpret it as markdown.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you need the string shown in the example

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Discord.Net you can use the [Format.Sanitize](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/265da99619a775d23b24326648fe4220bc6beeae/src/Discord.Net.Core/Format.cs#L36) method to escape all formatting characters. If you are not using this library, then just copy the code and create your own method.